# Failed to load response data

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap, codeigniter

Estoy utilizando `bootstrapTables` y quiero actualizar una tabla después de mandar ciertos parámetros.

Éste es el código:

```
function actualizarTabla(datoFechaIni, datoFechaFin) {
  $('#venta').bootstrapTable("refresh", {
      url: "<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/supervisor/supinicio/datos_ventas",
        query: {
          fechaIni: datoFechaIni,
          fechaFin: datoFechaFin
    }
  });
  }

function cargaInicial() {
  $("#e-fechaInicio").change(function() {
    actualizarTabla($("#e-fechaInicio").val(), $("#e-fechaFin").val());
  });
  $("#e-fechaFin").change(function() {
    actualizarTabla($("#e-fechaInicio").val(), $("#e-fechaFin").val());
  });
}
```

Al hacer esto me debe de *devolver un JSON* con mis datos, pero no lo hace se cancela la acción y aparece  `failed to load response data`. ¿Alguien sabe cuál es el error?.
Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Trata de imprimir el resultado de funcion, y asegurate de que esta devuelva una cadena > echo base_url();

Comment: ¿Qué error tienes? ¿400? ¿500? Necesitas decir qué respuesta está devolviendo el server.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar filtros en la tabla te recomiendo hacer uso de **queryParams**.
esta opción, te permite enviar la fecha inicio y fecha fin a tu controlador php llamado datos_ventas. para luego realizar dicho filtro en tu consulta sql, retornando así un json acotado

Puedes ver la documentación  [Aquí](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/documentation/).

```
$('#id_tabla').bootstrapTable({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'consulta_ejemplo.php',
        queryParams: function (p) {
            return {
                filtro_fecha_inicio: $('#datoFechaIni').val(),
                filtro_fecha_fin: $('#datoFechaFin').val()
        },
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            return "No existen datos";
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        striped: true,
        pagination: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 200],
        search: true,
        showColumns: false,
        showRefresh: true,
        clickToSelect: false,
        showPaginationSwitch: true,
        columns: [ {
                field: 'Id',
                title: 'ID',
                align: 'left',
                sortable: true,
                visible: true
            },{
                field: 'Nombre',
                title: 'Titulo',
                align: 'left',
                sortable: true,
        }]

});
```

Comment: Hola @felipe, podrías detallar un poco más lo qué aporta tu respuesta?

Comment: OK @Carmen, editado:  trate de explicar el objetivo de usar queryParams.

Comment: Hola @Felipe, pero esto cada que cambia los parámetros me refrescara mi tabla, automáticamente  por que por eso 
 usaba $('#venta').bootstrapTable("refresh", {} ya que leí que eso hace la función refresh?